# consume WCF service with javascript SOAP request

Tags: javascript, wcf, cordova, soap

I've got a WCF service and i have to consume it by using a JavaScript SOAP request. The JavaScript is part of a Phonegap application so I don't run this JavaScript from a local server but from a file.

When the WCF service is running localhost, everything works fine. But as soon as I deploy the WCF service on a server, I get the error (the name of the service and its methods are for illustration purposes):

```
OPTIONS http://myWebservice/service.svc 400 (Bad Request)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myWebservice/service.svc. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I know this is a cross-domain error but that's why added the following method to the global.asax of my webservice. But that doesn't help.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept,SOAPAction");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

The javascript call:

```
 $.support.cors = true;
        var bodyrequest = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                        "<s:Body>" +
                            "<"getAll xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" />" +
                          "</s:Body>" +
                        "</s:Envelope>";

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

            //This works
            //url: "http://localhost:49704/myWebservice/service.svc",

            //this doesn't work
            url: "http://myWebservice/service.svc",
            data: bodyrequest,
            timeout: 10000,
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/service/getAll ");
            },

        });
```

The web.config of the wcf service:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="myWebservice/service">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Contract.myWebservice"/>
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>

<appSettings>
  ...
</appSettings>
```

Does anyone have an idea? Or is there an other way to do a cross-domain SOAP Javascript request to a WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like old question. Have you already resolved it?
If not, can you post the actual request going to the server? Try to capture it with Fiddler.